# BB10 - ListView filter or search function?

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I have `ListVIew` that is filled with hard-coded `DataModel`. Then I want to create `DropDown` menu that contains the dataModel header.

When I select the `DropDown` option, I want `ListView` to only show the items for the selected header.

So, my questions are:

1. How can I do this in `QML`?
2. Is there any way to populate the `DropDown's` `Option` with the data model?

Below is my application's structure:

```
 Page{
     Container{
         DropDown{} //onSelectedValueChanged, I want the ListView filtered
         ListView{
              dataModel: XmlDataModel{...}
              listItemComponents: [...]
         }
     }
 }
```

Thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked [the question](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Cascades-Development/ListView-filter-or-search-function/m-p/2097691#M11583) in Blackberry support forum and got the answer:

If we follow the documentation, we know that dataModel looks like this:

```
<root>
    <header> ... </header>
    <header> ... </header>
    <header> ... </header>
</root>
```

Then we change the `rootIndexPath` to the index of the header. So only the child of that header is shown. The index is in array integer type

```
myListView.rootIndexPath = [0] //Show all child of first header
myListView.rootIndexPath = [1] //Show all child of second header
```